# Delete MYSQL values past the most recent 80

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently using:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 0, 80
```

to display the 80 most recent usernames, how can i make a query such that it deletes any other entries past this 80?

I presume i need a cron job, but what kind of query does it need to execute?

Comment: MySQL has a category called `event` which works like a built-in cron job, for your information.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?  Typically a requirement like "display only the most recent 80 users" is properly an application-level constraint rather than a storage-level constraint ("store at most only the most recent 80 users").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are different ways:

```
delete users from users
LEFT JOIN
(
  select id from users order by date_time DESC LIMIT 0, 80) t1 ON users.id=t1.id
where t1.id is null
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/079a0/1)

and without LIMIT:

```
delete users from users
LEFT JOIN
(
  select id from
(
SELECT  id, 
        @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM    users,(SELECT @curRow := 0) r
ORDER BY date_time DESC) t where row_number<=80
) t1 ON users.id=t1.id
where t1.id is null
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fcbc1/1)

Comment: I don't think this will work -- `Limit` may not be supported with `IN` clauses.

Comment: same as below:This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT &amp; IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' problematic

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a sub-query

```
DELETE FROM USERS where ID NOT IN
(SELECT ID FROM users ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 0, 80)
```

as you cannot use the limit when deleting

Comment: and that will delete everything PAST 80?

Comment: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT &amp; IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' problematic

Answer (score 1):

Try this by using `LEFT JOIN`.

```
DELETE  a
FROM    users a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ID
            FROM    users
            ORDER   BY date_time DESC 
            LIMIT   0, 80
        ) b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE   b.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Just to mention it has a unique username field if that matters?

Comment: aside from `username` do you have primary key? if so, use that column rather than the `username`.

Comment: Yes, it does have an ID column, but: You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Unknown column 'b.id' in 'where clause' strange, considering there CERTAINLY is an id column in users

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but possibly using a user variable to assign a sequence number:-

```
DELETE users
FROM users
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, @Sequence:=@Sequence + 1 AS aSequence
    FROM (SELECT ID, date_time FROM users ORDER BY date_time) a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Sequence:=0) b
) c
ON users.ID = c.ID
AND c.aSequence > 80
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using an intermediate subquery? Just a thought.

```
DELETE FROM `users`
   WHERE id NOT IN (
      SELECT id
      FROM (
         SELECT id
         FROM `users`
         ORDER BY date_time DESC
         LIMIT 80 
   ) AS q
);
```